# How to keep session data after redirect with PassportJS & Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm trying to redirect user to the originally issued URL after authenticating them to our own oauth2 server.
To do so I've read that it is possible to store data in the session object attached to the request. However I'm losing the data after the first redirect and consequently user are redirected to the fallback URL I provided.

Here is the code that initialize the app

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const auth = require('./auth');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  cookie: {
   secure: true,
   maxAge: 36000000
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

auth.config(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({ message: 'root' }));
app.get('/failure', (req, res) => res.json({ message: 'fail' }));

// load all the routes
require('../routes/posts')(router, auth);

app.use('/api', router);
app.use('/auth', auth.router);
```

The auth module is as follows :

```js
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');

const router = express.Router();

module.exports = {
  config (app) {
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user));
    passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => done(null, obj));

    passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
      authorizationURL,
      tokenURL,
      clientID,
      clientSecret,
      callbackURL
    },
    onAuthorize
    ));

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    router.get('/uaa', passport.authenticate('oauth2'));

    router.get('/oauth/callback', passport.authenticate('oauth2'), (req, res) => {
        req.session.save(err => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.redirect(req.session.redirectTo || '/');
        });
      });
  },

  ensureAuthenticated (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
    if (!req.session.redirectTo) req.session.redirectTo = req.originalUrl;
    req.session.save(err => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.redirect('/auth/uaa');
    });
  },

  router
};
```

And now if on the browser I request `http://localhost:3333/api/questions` (the matching route descrition is `router.route('/questions').get(auth.ensureAuthenticated, PostController.questions.getAll)`) I land in the `ensureAuthenticated` function which stores the initial route (`/api/questions`) but when I land in the final handler for my oauth2 callback, `req.session.redirectTo` does not exists. In fact it no longer exist right after the redirection to `/auth/uaa`.

- Am I configuring something wrong ?
- Are my router declarations okay ?
- Why can't I access the data I previously stored ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that I specified a secure cookie while serving content over HTTP.

Comment: Having this issue now. How'd you fix it?

Comment: In my specific case, it as https related. So I removed the secure cookie option and it worked as expected after that.